# Statistician's word for a distribution curve tailing less steeply to left or right

Tags: mathematics, statistics

I know the word `normal distribution`. But what does a statistician call it when the curve of the distribution tails less steeply (ie falls more gradually) to the left or right?

Comment: Do you mean "a positive/negative skew"?

Comment: I agree with Centaurus -- "[skewed curve](http://www.assetinsights.net/Concepts/Curve_Symmetrical_and_Skewed.JPG)".

Comment: Yes, the pictures tell me that I absolutly mean that. :D Please transfrom your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Skew** is the term that I learned in engineering school, 40-odd years ago.  If the plot of a "smooth" frequency distribution is not perfectly symmetrical it is said to be *skewed* (or possess [skewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness)) in one direction or the other.  (I'm a little fuzzy on what goes on if the distribution "curve" is ragged.)

A distribution can be skewed due to a longer "tail" on one side or a fatter tail or both.

*Skew* is a convenient term since it's basic meaning is intuitive to anyone with good familiarity with English, even though the detailed technical definition is [incredibly Greek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Pearson.27s_moment_coefficient_of_skewness).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's simply referred to as a **long-tail[ed] distribution**.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_tail) has:

> In statistics, a long tail of some distributions of numbers is the
> portion of the distribution having a large number of occurrences far
> from the "head" or central part of the distribution. The distribution
> could involve popularities, random numbers of occurrences of events
> with various probabilities, etc.
>
> A probability distribution is said
> to have a long tail if a larger share of population rests within its
> tail than would under a normal distribution. A long-tail distribution
> will arise with the inclusion of many values unusually far from the
> mean, which increase the magnitude of the skewness of the
> distribution. A long-tailed distribution is a particular type of
> heavy-tailed distribution.

Comment: "Long-tailed" is referring to the deviation from "normal" ("normal distribution", that is), not the degree of skew.  A normal distribution can still be skewed.

Comment: No it can't. The equation demands that there is a line of symmetry in the graph: it's a translated even function. You're talking about a 'skew normal distribution' (a three word compound); there's no such thing as a skewed 'normal distribution' {[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution)}. Are you a mathematician?

Comment: Are you a mathematician?

Comment: I taught maths to the level above A-level. Now, how about a retraction?

Comment: Did you read either of the linked articles?  (Did you even look at the pictures?)

Comment: @HotLicks I am a mathematician and I work with probability and I confirm that the normal distribution cannot be skewed. The probability distribution function is a Gaussian curve.

Comment: @MattSamuel - So what terminology do you use for an asymmetrical distribution?

Comment: Certainly a distribution can be skew, that's a fine term. But then it's not a normal distribution anymore (there may be such a thing as a "skew normal distribution", but that's different from a normal distribution; everybody knows what you're talking about when you say "normal distribution.").

Comment: @Hotlicks anyway, I would probably use "asymmetrical" or "skew distribution." As far as I know this answer is fine though. A statistician has more use for precise names of distributions. I was just putting in my two cents to confirm that normal distribution has a standard meaning.

Comment: @Hotlicks by the way, I'm new here, from mathematics se, where voting abounds. What does it take to get an upvote on this site?